# String Tokenizer JOptionPane

Tags: java

I have a quick question in regards to String Tokenizer. I am fiddling around with this silly program to practice for a quiz in school next week (on String Tokenizer) and I was wondering if any of you could provide me some information on how to print the tokens all in one clump, but obviously separated... For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*; 

public class stringTokenizer
{

public static void main (String [] args)
{


String questionData = "Who was the first US president#George Clooney#George             

    Washington#Washington Irving#Irving Berlin";

String delimiters = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Enter a delimiter" );

StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer ( questionData, delimiters );

System.out.println("\nThe string " + questionData+" has "+  

parser.countTokens()+ " tokens");
String input = " ";

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (parser.nextToken ( ) );

            while (!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("George Clooney") && input.equalsIgnoreCase("George Washington") && input.equalsIgnoreCase("Washington Irving") && input.equalsIgnoreCase("Irving Berlin")))
            {

                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (parser.nextToken ( ));

            }
if (input == "George Washington")

{
 System.out.println ("YAY! You know the first president of the United       

 States!");
}

else 

{
System.out.println ("Yer dumb...");
}
System.exit (0);
}
}
```

What is happening is: 
Each token gets print off into a JOptionPane... I just want it in one JOptionPane but to look like:

```
Who was the first president?
George Clooney
George Washington
George Irving
Irving Berlin
```

Like that! I know it is because I am using "nextToken" but I am not sure what to replace there instead and what nots.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I don't understand why your professor is teaching you the `StringTokenizer` class.  In the words of the Javadoc - "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code".  It might be worthwhile making your professor aware of this, so that he/she doesn't waste any more of your time on this.

Comment: Also, `if (input == "George Washington")` doesn't do what you think it does.  The proper way to compare `String` objects is with the `equals` method.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that you loop through your while loop, you are creating a new JOptionPane:

```
 while (!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("George Clooney") && input.equalsIgnoreCase("George Washington") && input.equalsIgnoreCase("Washington Irving") && input.equalsIgnoreCase("Irving Berlin")))
        {

            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (parser.nextToken ( ));

        }
```

This is why you are getting multiple pop up windows and each time they have a difference message, which is one of your tokens.  Your use of StringTokenizer is correct, it is the logic around displaying it that is throwing you off.  Instead, try looping through all of the tokens to create the string that is going to be in the pop up window, and then create the pop up window one time in order to get your input, as follows:

```
  StringBuilder display = new StringBuilder();
        int tokens = parser.countTokens();
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens; i++)
        {
            display.append(parser.nextToken() + "\r\n");
        }
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (display.toString());
```

You are saying that you meant to validate the input with the while loop; so you can still do that with the above code; but you're code right now will still not create the message in the dialog appropriately, and if you enter invalid input enough times, it will throw an exception because parser will run out of nextToken()s.  In order to remedy this issue and do what you would like to do, after the line of code above, you can change your while loop to like:

```
while (!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("George Clooney") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("George Washington") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("Washington Irving") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("Irving Berlin")))
                    {

                        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (display);

                    }
```

Since we are using equalsIgnoreCase, we should use the same method in our if statements to see if the question was answered correctly:

```
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("George Washington"))
```

Also, notice that I changed the logic in the while loop to OR as opposed to AND because we want the while loop to continue running if each of those return false, not if any one of them returns false, and the negation in front of all of them will mean that we need to do a logical OR on all of the possibilities.

Comment: What I was trying to do is a while loop for data validation... I don't understand why a while loop would chop it into pieces. I want it all in ONE piece. also it clearly happens before the while loop even begins.